# How can I load .FBX files?

Tags: directx, blender, fbx

I am looking into options for the model assets for my game. I have gotten pretty good with Blender, and want to use C++/DirectX9 (don't need all the excess from 10+), but Blender 2.6 exports .fbx not .x (by nature) and supposedly what is exported from Blender to .x is not entirely stable.

In short how do I import .fbx models (I can work around not having animations if I must) into DirectX9? Is there a middleware, or conversion tool that will maintain stability?

Comment: FWIW, D3D10 (and 11, which is better) actually streamlines the feature set quite a lot from D3D9, and the extra verbosity it's adding is largely a side-effect of being a more direct and accurate representation of what's going on with your card anyhow. Unless you really need to support XP, you may want to reconsider your options (but go for 11 if you do, since it's all-around better than 10).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The canonical middleware for loading and manipulating FBX data in C++ would likely be the [official FBX SDK from Autodesk](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=7478532).